# PhpStorm highlight part of file as JavaScript with custom start and end lines

Tags: javascript, php, phpstorm

I have inherited a PHP project that contains several HTML files with the following structure

```
<?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureStart(); ?>

    var some = javascript.goesHere();

<?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureEnd(); ?>

<div class="some html goes here">

   <h1> <?php echo "with some php in the middle"; ?> </h1>

</div>
```

Would it be possible to configure Phpstorm to interpret everything between the placeholder lines as JS and the rest of the file as HTML with some PHP?

I know the file structure is very unfortunate, but I can not refactor it for now...

Thanks

Comment: Unfortunately NO -- PhpStorm does not support such approach at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably not really what you want but if you surround the javascript with a script tab phpstorm will interpret it as js. You would need to change your code to look like:

```
<script>
<?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureStart(); ?>

    var some = javascript.goesHere();

<?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureEnd(); ?>
</script>
<div class="some html goes here">

   <h1> <?php echo "with some php in the middle"; ?> </h1>

</div>
```

This article says you can use two file extentions to accomplish something similar without using the script tags.

https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Syntax+highlighting+of+PHP+inside+JavaScript+(and+other+languages)

Comment: Based on the code example I may say that it may pollute generated HTML with empty script tags: quite likely that the JS code between `captureStart()` and `captureEnd()` will be kept separately and then dumped in one go at the end of the page. But yes -- such approach will help with syntax coloring.

Comment: Agreed the extra script tags will probably be annoying on the front end. But just throwing out workable options. The article is a more promising solution.

Comment: Thanks danielson317.

That does work, but I was hopping for a solution that did not require me to alter the existing files. And as LazyOne sugested it does dump empty script tags. I suppose your answer is as good as I am going to get so I will mark as accepted.

Answer (score 1):

There are at least two interesting possibilities...

### 1. *Heredoc* notation

https://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc
For me the most interesting solution was to transform the *JavaScript* into a *PHP* string using the *heredoc* syntax:

```
<div>
    <div>
        <?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureStart(); ?>
        <?= <<<JS
            var some = javascript.goesHere();
JS
        ?>
        <?php $this->placeholder('dom.ready')->captureEnd(); ?>
    </div>
</div>
```

***Ensure to place the closing identifier in the first column of line***

### 2. Change the filename

When you change your file extension from `.php` into `.js.php` *PhpStorm* will also highlight your *JavaScript*.

I think this solution is nice because you will always be remembered that *JavaScript* is in your *PHP* file. And this has to be cleared out...

---

Both solutions was found on *jetbrains.com*. Thanks to Andriy Bazanov:

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/207046645-Zend-framework-and-code-formating-in-view-files

https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/posts/115000790544-Syntax-Highligth-on-some-special-cases